# ubuntu 12.04 cannot be powered off completely

Tags: shutdown

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 recently. 
When I try to power off, the hard disk seem to be powered off. However, the computer cannot be powered off completely. The power light and Bluetooth light is still on.

It usually happens when I use the computer for a while. If I try to power off just after starting, it would probably succeed.